# Modify the instancer object into instanced object

Tags: java, swing, object, jtable

I have an object A that instance another object B.
I was wondering whether or not is possible to modify A with instructions in B.
In my circumstance, I have a Timetable (its code is under "Object A") that open (by `InsertLesson.setVisible(true);`) a Window to let the user compile its cells with lesson. At this time, the Window (`InsertLesson`, code under "object B") get the lesson selection by user but it is not able to write in the table that selection. How can I do?

Here the code

Object A:

```
public class TablePanel extends JPanel
{
private JTable table;
public Tabella()
{
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 
    table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);     
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
    JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(jps);
    add(new JScrollPane(table));
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.addMouseListener(
        new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int row = table.rowAtPoint(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
            int col = table.columnAtPoint(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));

            if (col>0) {
            if (e.getClickCount() > 1) {
            if (row == 5 | row == 6) 
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Impossible to set lesson.");

                    return;
                }
            else {
                table.getColumnName(col);
                String day = table.getColumnName(col);
                String hour = (String) table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                InsertLesson cell = new InsertLesson(day, hour);
                cel.setVisible(true);

                 }
                }
              }
            }
    }
    );
}
private class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private String[] columns = {"","Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

private String[][] data = {{"8:30 - 9:30","","","","","",""},
        {"9:30 - 10:30","","","","","",""},
        {"10:30 - 11:30","","","","","",""},
        {"11:30 - 12:30","","","","","",""},
        {"12:30 - 13:30","","","","","",""},
        {"13:30 - 14:30","","","","","",""},
        {"14:30 - 15:30","","","","","",""},
        {"15:30 - 16:30","","","","","",""},
        {"16:30 - 17:30","","","","","",""}};

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columns[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }
}
```

Object B (which has to modify A):

```
public InsertLesson (String day, String hour)
        { 
            initialize(day, hour);
        }

        private void initialize(String day, String hour) {


            this.setSize(600,200);
            this.setTitle("Insert Lesson");
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            String[] lessons = {"math", "english", "art"};
            String [] classrooms = {"class1", "class2"};    

            JPanel centralPnl = new JPanel();
            this.getContentPane().add(centralPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);


            final JComboBox classBox = new JComboBox(classrooms );
            centralPnl.add(classBox);

            final JComboBox lessonsBox = new JComboBox(lessons);
            centralPnl.add(lessonsBox);

            JPanel southPnl = new JPanel();
            this.getContentPane().add(southPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            JButton insLessonBtn = new JButton("Insert Lesson");
            southPnl.add(insLessonBtn);

            lessonsBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

                    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    {
                        selectedLesson = lessonsBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    }
                }
            });

            classBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

                    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    {
                        selectedClass = classBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    }


                }


            });

            class  MouseSpy implements MouseListener
            {
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Do something for modify table with\n"
                                + "values of selectedLesson and selectedClass");
                    }
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            }

            MouseListener listener = new MouseSpy();
            insLessonBtn.addMouseListener(listener);

        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Unless you articulate your question better, it's difficult to help you. The problem with that is that you have seen the problem, and we're trying to see it from your words.

Comment: Just Edit. Look at introduction: is my situation clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the table in *A*, *B* must invoke the method `setValueAt()` on the `TableModel` of `A`. Alternatively, add a method to your `TableModel` that does the update. A typical implementation of `setValueAt()` is seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data). If that doesn't help, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you encounter.

Addendum: *I want to update the table … after the user press the … button.*

As a concrete example using your `TableModel`, the <kbd>Update</kbd> button below updates the table's model with each press. Compare the implmentation of `setValueAt ()` to the one cited above. The button's `actionPerformed()` method accesses a `final` reference to the `TableModel` in the enclosing scope, but you can pass a reference to your `TableModel` as a parameter to the constructor of `InsertLesson`.

Addendum: *Would you write [it for] me?*

No, but I will outline the approach, assuming a class `InsertLesson`,

```
TableModel model = new MyTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(model);
InsertLesson cell = new InsertLesson(day, hour, model);
…
class InsertLesson {

    TableModel model;

    public InsertLesson(String day, String hour, TableModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        …
    }
    …
}
```

[image: table image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18764073/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private static class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private String[] columns = {
            "Time", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
        private String[][] data = {
            {"8:30 - 9:30", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"9:30 - 10:30", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"10:30 - 11:30", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"11:30 - 12:30", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"12:30 - 13:30", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"13:30 - 14:30", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"14:30 - 15:30", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"15:30 - 16:30", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"16:30 - 17:30", "", "", "", "", ""}};

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columns[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = (String) aValue;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final TableModel model = new MyTableModel();
        f.add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(600, 128);
            }
        }));
        f.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Update") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.setValueAt(String.valueOf(e.getWhen() % 1000000), 1, 1);
            }
        }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I invoke the method `setValueAt()` on the `TableModel` **from B**? This is the core of my problem. And this is the problem I try to resolve. If tell me this, you'll find my solution

Comment: I just want to update the table that instance `InsertLesson` after the user press the `insLessonBtn` button. Have you any idea?

Comment: Pass a reference to your `TableModel` as a parameter to the constructor of _B_.

Comment: ok I thank you, but there is a significative difference: In my object B I can't see the `abstractTableModel model` so I can't apply the set `setValueAt()` method in B. Am I clear? In which way would you do? Thanks again

Comment: Add a third parameter to your `InsertLesson` constructor to hold a reference to your `MyTableModel` instance.