# not understood Java syntax of defined Constructor

Tags: java, swing, constructor

I'm Implementing a type of table. To do this, I have used an `AbstractTableModel`, but I don't know what my code is doing (that's why I get a snippet that did his work, but obviously I want to understand). You can see the code

```
public class TablePanel extends JPanel
{
    private JTable table;
    public TablePanel()
    {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 
        table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);     
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
        JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(jps);
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    }
    private class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columns = {"","Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
        private String[][] data = {{"8:30 - 9:30","","","","","",""},
            {"9:30 - 10:30","","","","","",""},
            {"10:30 - 11:30","","","","","",""},
            {"11:30 - 12:30","","","","","",""},
            {"12:30 - 13:30","","","","","",""},
            {"13:30 - 14:30","","","","","",""},
            {"14:30 - 15:30","","","","","",""},
            {"15:30 - 16:30","","","","","",""},
            {"16:30 - 17:30","","","","","",""}};

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columns[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }
        public Object myMethod (){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Well, what does it mean `table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());`?
I thought that `table` would be a `MyTableModel` instance, but that is not true. In fact, if I pass table to another external class, this class won't see the method `myMethod` defined in the body of `MyTableModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MyTableModel` is a `TableModel`, but a `TableModel` is *not* necessarily a `MyTableModel`.

As you know your table's model is an instance of `MyTableModel`, which has the desired `myMethod()`, you can use a cast:

```
JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel) table.getModel();
```

It may be easier to create and use a reference to your model:

```
MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Don't neglect to include the implementation of `setValueAt()`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764073/230513).

Comment: @Bernheart  [ead API, there are pre_implemented contructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28%29), otherwise without any definition for XxxTableModel is there set DefaultTableModel ....

Answer (score 0):

a JTable constructor accepts any Object of a class that implements the `TableModel` interface

[**this**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) will help you learn more.

Answer (score 0):

its expected behaviour that other classes cant see the function myMethod because they "think" that your MyTableModel is just a AbstractTableModel (which in fact it isnt)
The code and everything else you put into MyTableModel is callen correctly but you just cant see the function myMethod
Thats because youre using a OOP language

So no youre wrong.
Youre creating a instance of MyTableModel so everything you do inside will be executed if you call

you should read this here which will explain more about the OOP part:
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/understanding-javas-objectoriented-programming-oop.html

just to say it quick

If you need to access your myMethod function just cast it like so:
     // Create the MyTableInstance (this is possible because AbstractTableModel is the parent and MyTableModel is the child)
     AbstractTableModel atmTestVariable = new MyTableModel();

```
 // Now to be able to call this:
 // atmTestVariable.myMethod();
 // we need to do this:

 if(atmTestVariable isntanceof MyTableModel) //make sure that atmTestVariable is REALY a MyTableModel
 {
    MyTableModel mtmTemp = (MyTableModel)atmTestVariable; //cast to MyTableModel
    mtmTemp.myMethod(); //Call the function
    // and now the short variant:
    ((MyTableModel)atmTestVariable).myMethod(); //cast to MyTableModel AND call the function
 }
```

Hopefully i was able to help

Ohhh and please move the define of your MyTabelModel class into a seperate file : /